# Replace index value with actual filename

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I have the following code:

```
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

path = 'some path'

textIN = [os.path.join(dirpath, f) for dirpath, dirnames, files in 
    os.walk(path) for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')]
docs = [open(f) for f in textIN]
print textIN
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(input='file', encoding='utf-8', 
    stop_words='english', norm='l2').fit_transform(docs)
pair = tfidf * tfidf.T
print pair
```

It works fine and outputs the following:

```
[filename, filename, filename, etc.]    
 (0, 7)        0.0993597661923
 (0, 8)        0.0118954936469
 (0, 9)        0.147109830057
 (0, 10)       0.0791162122306
 (0, 6)        0.0433550484844
 (0, 5)        0.0892228473038
 (0, 4)        0.0356736412472
 (0, 3)        0.693555573615
 (0, 2)        0.0346887846227
 (0, 1)        0.0279157259462
 (0, 0)        1.0
 (1, 0)        0.0279157259462
 (1, 7)        0.0395168969129
 (1, 8)        0.0247319167695
 (1, 9)        0.110314319112
 (1, 5)        0.0348945360205
 (1, 4)        0.288812927116
 (1, 3)        0.0966845883594
 (1, 10)       0.153976266391
 (1, 6)        0.271902487932
 (1, 2)        0.100596627508
 (1, 1)        1.0
 (2, 0)        0.0346887846227
 (2, 1)        0.100596627508
 (2, 8)        0.0127731857591
 :     :
 (8, 6)        0.0380354696531
```

I would like to be able to replace the index values with the respective filenames, as well as display all results.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Make sure you're clear about what is input, what is output, what is in the files and what structure (if any) the file names have.

Comment: My question/problem literally answers everything you just said.